# Can't Create Project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Error:failed to create directory 'D:\rw_apps\MyApplication\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\bhavin\myapplication'**

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:

Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt

I tried lots of solution from other stackoverflow answers like 
clean project, 
restart android studio, 
change build-tools,
re-download build-tools.

> **Run with --stacktrace are long so I share text file please [check](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1g2vrunqjm29hz9/stackstarce.txt?dl=0) it.**
>
> I am using android studio 3.0 beta 6.

MY gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android.enableAapt2=false` in your `gradle.properties` file

Comment: It's work but I got error in every project means new and old all. so It's temporary solution(Jugaad) not permanent please tell me in details whats aapt2 and whats main problem .

Comment: It is a known issue with new Android Studio release. Google has mentioned [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html) it is a temporary issue and will be resolved soon.